Build Config in multiple files in flutter project
When running the project, this error occurs:

ERROR:/Users/sam/AndroidStudioProjects/Demo-Project/build/flutter_keyboard_visibility/.transforms/c7d68dcefb1368ccf411da72a1878924/transformed/debug/com/x/BuildConfig.dex:
D8: Type com.x.BuildConfig is defined multiple times:
/Users/sam/AndroidStudioProjects/Demo-Project/build/flutter_keyboard_visibility/.transforms/c7d68dcefb1368ccf411da72a1878924/transformed/debug/com/x/BuildConfig.dex,
/Users/sam/AndroidStudioProjects/Demo-Project/build/flutter_native_timezone/.transforms/2ec4e215d60d1e5ccf50cbf576a7cd55/transformed/debug/com/x/BuildConfig.dex
Type com.x.BuildConfig is defined multiple times:
/Users/sam/AndroidStudioProjects/Demo-project/build/flutter_keyboard_visibility/.transforms/c7d68dcefb1368ccf411da72a1878924/transformed/debug/com/x/BuildConfig.dex,
/Users/sam/AndroidStudioProjects/Demo-project/build/flutter_native_timezone/.transforms/2ec4e215d60d1e5ccf50cbf576a7cd55/transformed/debug/com/x/BuildConfig.dex
at
com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
at
com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:858)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:804)
at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at
org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
at
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:170)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)    at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)    at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
Source)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown
Source)   at
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
Source)   at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
Source)   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I upgraded the dependencies using pub upgrade. Can please any one explain why this error is coming from when I have uprgrded my android studio version.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
